# Import Scala object within object in Java

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I have an object within another object in Scala which I want to import in Java. The setup is something like this:

Scala:

```scala
package scalapart;

object Outer {
    object Inner {
        def method: String = "test"
    }
}
```

Java:

```java
import scalapart.Outer.Inner;
...
Outer.Inner.method()
```

Unfortunately, I get `cannot find symbol` in line 1 of the Java code. And if I `import scalapart.Outer;`, then the second line reports the same issue.

Is there a way to import a Scala object that is defined inside another Scala object in Java?

Answer (score 2):

You can either used it directly:

```
    // assuming they are in the same package:
    String mystr = Outer.Inner$.MODULE$.method();
    System.out.println(mystr);  // test

    // if in other package just:
    import packageName.Outer;

    String mystr = Outer.Inner$.MODULE$.method();
```

Or do a `static import` and use it like this (or similar):

```
import static packageName.Outer.Inner$.MODULE$;

String mystr = MODULE$.method();
```

Java doesn’t have any direct equivalent to the singleton object, so for every Scala singleton object, the compiler creates a synthetic Java class with the same name plus a dollar sign appended at the end) for that `object` and a `static` field named `MODULE$` to hold the single instance of the class. So, to ensure there is only one instance of an object, Scala uses a static class holder.

Your disassembled code looks something like this:

```
public final class Outer
{
    public static class Inner$
    {
        public static final Inner$ MODULE$;

        static {
            MODULE$ = new Inner$();
        }

        public String method() {
            return "test";
        }
    }
}

public final class Outer$ {
    public static final Outer$ MODULE$;

    static {
        MODULE$ = new Outer$();
    }

    private Outer$() {
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the import statement in the first example?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add it: import it with using it's packageName: `import mypackage.Outer;` should work. Intellij will figure it out.  Updated the answer to include this.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I will try to recreate this MWE and report back.

Comment: What Scala version are you using? I tested this with Scala  2.13.8.